# Varnish log cache not filtering requests correctly

Tags: varnish

Something weird is going on with my varnishlog.

I am trying to filter all the requests in the varnishlog that have a ban, so I try this:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "BAN"'
```

This gets all BAN and GET request, which is weird.

If I try:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "POST"'
```

It works just fine and only shows the POST requests.

If I try:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "ABSOLUTELYWRONG"'
```

It doesn't show anything at all, as expected.

So everything works fine except BAN.

I expect BAN to only show BAN requests.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

EDIT here is an example of what I am getting using the BAN filter which should not be here because it's a GET:

```
*4* << Request  >> 163935    
-4- Begin          req 163934 esi
-4- ReqURL         someUrl
-4- ReqUnset       Host: myhost.local.es
-4- ReqHeader      Host: myhost.local.es
-4- ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip
-4- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-4- Timestamp      Start: 1572426799.985887 0.000000 0.000000
-4- ReqStart       127.0.0.1 47748
-4- ReqMethod      GET
-4- ReqURL         someUrl
-4- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-4- ReqHeader      X-Host: .*
-4- ReqHeader      X-Url: .*
-4- ReqHeader      X-Content-Type: .*
-4- ReqHeader      X-Cache-Tags: (?<=,|^)(my-tag-9000
-4- ReqHeader      User-Agent: Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
-4- ReqHeader      Host: myhost.local.com
-4- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-4- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-4- VCL_call       RECV
-4- VCL_acl        MATCH localhost "localhost"
-4- ReqHeader      Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0
-4- VCL_return     hash
-4- VCL_call       HASH
-4- VCL_return     lookup
-4- Hit            32870 31533030.619874 86400.000000 0.000000
-4- VCL_call       HIT
-4- VCL_return     deliver
-4- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-4- RespStatus     200
-4- RespReason     OK
-4- RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
-4- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-4- RespHeader     Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=31536000
-4- RespHeader     X-Cache-Debug: 1
-4- RespHeader     X-Cache-Tags: twig-randomnumber
-4- RespHeader     X-Debug-Token: 9e5c89
-4- RespHeader     X-Debug-Token-Link: mydebugtokenlink
-4- RespHeader     Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2019 08:23:50 GMT
-4- RespHeader     X-Url: /my/url/
-4- RespHeader     X-Host: myhost.local.com
-4- RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-4- RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-4- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 163935 32870
-4- RespHeader     Age: 2969
-4- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
-4- VCL_call       DELIVER
-4- RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
-4- RespUnset      X-Cache-Tags: twig-randomnumber
-4- RespUnset      X-Url: someUrl
-4- RespUnset      X-Varnish: 163935 32870
-4- RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
-4- RespUnset      Age: 2969
-4- RespUnset      Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=31536000
-4- RespUnset      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-4- RespHeader     Vary: User-Agent, Accept-Encoding
-4- RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
-4- VCL_return     deliver
-4- Timestamp      Process: 1572426799.985903 0.000016 0.000016
-4- RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-4- RespHeader     Content-Length: 43
-4- Timestamp      Resp: 1572426799.985922 0.000035 0.000020
-4- ReqAcct        0 0 0 0 28 28
-4- End
```

Comment: It would be very useful to see the full log of one of those `GET` requests unexpectedly matching `sudo varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "BAN"'`. In any case, my bet is `ReqMethod` is rewritten from `GET` to `BAN` (or `BAN` to `GET`) at some point during the request.

Comment: @CarlosAbalde Added one as an example.

Comment: Still not enough to troubleshoot this because what you shared in an ESI sub-request. That one does not match `ReqMethod eq "BAN"`, but the expression is going to be evaluated against all other ESI sub-requests and the top-level request too.